# Auto refresh browser automatically in iOS

Tags: ios

I am working on an iPhone app where i am sending an image from the app to the server and that image is displayed on the browser.

Is there any way that i can refresh browser automatically through my app? Or is this something that should be handled from server side only and we cannot do anything from our app? Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your iOS app could call some script on the server, and the server could use websockets to tell the client browser to refresh, with a bit of JavaScript.

Comment: makes sense. But it would be great if you could provide me some sample code for this if you have:-)

Comment: I don't, I'm not in web development these days. That's a very basic use of websockets though, so feel free to search by yourself and further edit your question if you have specific points of trouble.